# Delegate to private function as argument for method in different class

Tags: c#, delegates, function-pointers

Let's take class `A` with private methods `f()` and `g()`. Let class `B` have public method `h`. Is it possible to pass pointer/delegate pointing to `A.g` from method `A.f` to `B.h`?

Consider the following code:

```
Class B
{
    public B() {}

    public h(/*take pointer/delegate*/)
    {
        //execute method from argument
    }
}

Class A
{
    private int x = 0;
    private void g()
    {
        x = 5;
    }

    private void f()
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.h(/*somehow pass delegate to g here*/);
    }
}
```

After `A.f()` is called I would like `A.x` to be `5`. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: is h supposed to be private or public?

Comment: @tam - public, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an `Action` argument to your method:

```
public h(Action action)
{
    action();
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
b.h(this.g);
```

Possibly worth noting that there are generic versions of `Action` that represent methods with parameters. For example, an `Action<int>` would match any method with a single `int` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible:

```
class B
{
    public B() {}

    public void h(Action a)
    {
        a();
    }
}

class A
{
    private int x = 0;
    private void g()
    {
        x = 5;
    }

    private void f()
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.h(g);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R8uZYz) is a fiddle showing that it works - I changed a few privates to public for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

```
class B
{
    public B()
    {
    }

    public void h(Action func)
    {
        func.Invoke();
        // or
        func();
    }
}

class A
{
    private int x = 0;

    private void g()
    {
        x = 5;
    }

    private void f()
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.h(g);
    }
}
```